# XP Security after support for LAN file transfers

Tags: networking, windows-xp, security

I'll make a long story short.  I have an XP computer that is used to run a machine in our factory.  Our machine vendor will not perform an upgrade to a newer version of windows.  I am required to keep it connected so we can transfer files over the LAN.

I want to keep the computer secure after support ends in April for XP.  My plan is to block all ports except those required for file transfer with windows firewall.  Will that be enough?  I'd like to use a 3rd party firewall system but it needs use an extremely low amount of CPU/RAM resources as not to interfere with running the machine.

Answer (score 1):

The built in firewall will be enough a 3rd party firewall will likely not provide any more protection. However the LAN file transfer service is where a majority of the viruses use to exploit and attack so you may be out of luck anyway.

Just try and keep a virus protection on it and keep it up to date.